# How to include table fo contents when using singlehtml build option?

Tags: python-sphinx, tableofcontents

### Context

I am using Sphinx to create technical documentation (not code-related). The input are several reStructuredText and SVG files. The output is created using the `singlehtml` builder (which is converted to PDF using weasyprint in a later step).

### Problem

I would like to include a table of contents (TOC) in the final document. The default location for the TOC (sidebar) is not an option. I have to disable/hide the sidebar to generate a useful PDF.

### Solutions (I have considered / tried)

- [`toctree` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html): Seems to only work with the sidebar, no matter what I try.
- [HTML Theming](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/theming.html): I'm using it for styling the HTML output, but I would not know how to address the TOC issue.
- [Sphinx extensions](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/index.html): I wrote my own, but it's not very flexible and I'm still sure that others have already solved this problem.
- Use `latexpdf` builder: Tried that and it solves the TOC problem, but it creates a few other problems and styling the document is so much easier for me using CSS.
- Other tool than Sphinx: Is this a typical case of an XY problem? I would like to use reStructuredText and SVGs to generate a PDF, but I would be open to use something else than Sphinx.

Comment: Interesting problem. If all other options don't work a last resort that should be guaranteed to work is to creating a nested list of cross-references by hand. This last option implies loosing some automation but you gain fine-tuned control of how the TOC is built and rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`contents` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents).

> Here's the directive in its simplest form:
>
> ```
> .. contents::
> ```
>
> Language-dependent boilerplate text will be used for the title. The English default title text is "Contents".
>
> An explicit title may be specified:
>
> ```
> .. contents:: Table of Contents
> ```

Comment: Will this really work? `.. contents::` only produces a TOC for the current file, but in the question it says that the input consists of several reStructuredText files.

Comment: I haven't tried it. I'm awaiting to see what the OP tries and reports back.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @StevePiercy. I've tried `.. contents..` before, but didn't think of the implications. I'll accept your answer and post another one showing my current solution.

Comment: @TomPohl I didn't suggest this right away although I suspected it would probably work. `.. contents::` creates a TOC for the file it is placed in, so because you are generating 1 single file it should work for all the contents. It makes sense `toctree` doesn't work because all the external files you reference are now being lumped into 1 single file. Your use of `.. include::` works because essentially it's a substitution (inclusion) that afterwards gets processed by `.. contents::`.

Answer (score 1):

As @mzjn already suspected, `.. contents::` only lists the contents of the current file, *but* if I use `.. include::` instead of `.. toctree::` to include other documents, it works nevertheless. So what I'm currently using is this:

```
.. sectnum::
.. contents:: Table of Contents
   :depth: 2

.. include:: intro.rst
.. include:: processes.rst
```